# How to add sound to notification?

Tags: android, audio, notifications

How do you add sound to a notification created by NotificationCompat.Builder?
I created a raw folder in res and added the sound there. So how do I now add it to notification? This is my Notification code

```
    int NOTIFY_ID=100;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Notification.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setContentTitle("Warning")
            .setContentText("Help!")

    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: There's a [setSound](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSound(android.net.Uri)) method in [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html).  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem here is how to reference the sound with a `Uri`, as there is an obvious method in the `NotificationCompat.Builder` class - `setSound(Uri soundUri)`.

To access your `raw` resources you need to create the `Uri` as follows:

> android.resource://[PACKAGE_NAME]/[RESOURCE_ID]

So the code could end up looking like that:

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifysnd);
mBuilder.setSound(sound);
```

Comment: What format does my sound file need to be in? I'm getting a default sound instead of my own.

Comment: I've answered my own question with trial and error: 1) mp3 works, wav doesn't, and 2) I need to disable the default sound by building the notification and then doing `n.defaults &= ~Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;`

Comment: If you are using Notification.Builder,  *builder.setDefaults(~Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);* will do the trick. Thanks to @karl for the tip

Answer (score 16):

To play a sound with your notification:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
```

Do normal notification procedures

To play the default sound with your notification:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

To play a custom sound with your notification:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/notification/notification.mp3");
```

Then just use the notification manager to send the notification.
If both of these statements are used, the application will default to using the default sound.

Comment: default sound doesn't work on Android 4-7 for me with `NotificationCompat` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56407328/notificationcompat-priority-default-doesnt-make-sound-on-older-android-versions

Answer (score 1):

For Android 8 (Oreo) and above you should use [Notification Channel](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) to show notifications, and they will automatically have sound if you haven't disabled it.

For older devices you can set sound with Notification Builder.
You can use `Notification.Builder.setSound()` to set custom sound, or you can use

`Notification.Builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)`
to set default sound.

There are also [defaults](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setDefaults(int)) for vibration and lights

Comment: default sound doesn't work on Android 4-7 for me with `NotificationCompat` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56407328/notificationcompat-priority-default-doesnt-make-sound-on-older-android-versions